# HTML within HTML

Tags: html

I am trying build an static HTML page that can perform a task. This page needs to be independent and not download anything or access any external resource from disk or online.

It is easy to place the JScripts that I need within the script tag. However, I need an HTML template file to be incorporated within this main HTML file...without being visible.

Basically the main page needs to copy this internal HTML into memory, perform some operations on it.

How can I incorporate that template in the main HTML file? Please note my problem is not knowing how to store the template in the main HTML somewhere, so that when the user clicks a certain button, I can read this HTML template from the main/current file to memory to do my operations.

Some snippets:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <title>Main HTML</title>
    <body>

    </body>
 </html>
```

and my template is something like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <title>Template HTML</title>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: _Basically the main page needs to copy this internal HTML into memory, perform some operations on it and then get downloaded..._ Not clear what you trying to ask

Comment: If you are about visibility for user in browser take a look here http://htmlbook.ru/css/visibility

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You can ignore the download part. My challenge is how to incorporate that template into the main HTML file and how to read it. After that I can handle the manuplation/download/save as operations.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski, no. I just need to know how to store that HTML template somewhere within the main HTML file.

Comment: Do you mean the Template tag?

Comment: _"the main page needs to copy this internal HTML into memory, perform some operations on it."_ you need javascript to describe actions. `<script type="text/javascript"> var templateCode = "HERE GOES YOUR HTML TEMPLATE OR READ FILE OPERATION"; /* AND AFTER THIS YOU CAN DO YOUR OPERATIONS HERE */ </script>`

Comment: Thanks. I guess that solves my problem partially but need something to escape all the tags and everything as it also has its own script section, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a JavaScript string literal (or a template literal).

```
const myTemplate = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=en><title>Template title</title>.......";
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess that solves my problem partially but need something to escape all the tags and everything as it also has its own script section, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much @Quentin. I think that solves my problem. I wish ppl hadn't downvote me so much. I don't have that much point.

Answer (score 1):

you need JavaScript to describe actions.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head> <title>Main HTML</title> </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const templateCode = `<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head> <title>Template HTML</title> </head>
        <body>

        </body>
        </html>`;
        alert(templateCode);
    </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Quentin's reply was what I needed.